# What is the right Uri syntax for multilevel navigation in ODATA?

Tags: odata

I have an ODATA Service MyService with entities Customers,Products and Categories, where Navigation Property is defined from Customers to Products, and from Products to Categories.

I am confused about the correct form of Uri to do Navigation from Customer to Product to Categories.

Initially I gave MyService/Customers(1)/Products(10)/Categories, but it gave me an error.

Then I tried MyService/Customers(1)/Products/Categories which worked correctly. I saw many examples in the internet in the form of the uri which I tried initially But it does not work for me.

Can anyone explain about this?

Answer (score 2):

The correct form of URI depends on the multiplicity of the navigation property Products.  If a Customer can have multiple Products then the first form is correct.  If a Customer can have at most one product then the second form is correct.

Perhaps in your service this navigation property has had the multiplicity set incorrectly.

Comment: Seems right. Products multiplicity is set as 1. But even so does the first have to give an error? Considering the id is correctly given as 1?

Comment: As a badly formed URL it should do, yes.  The specification makes a special distinction between the two cases, the syntax production entityNavProperty-et is defined to achieve navigation to a single entity and the special navPath-np is the variant that follows it in this situation.  I've always assumed that the 'np' stood for "no parentheses" to emphasise that they're not allowed at that point.

Answer (score 0):

> The use of parenthesis to specify the resource key indicates that this is an OData v4 topic.

According to the specification [OData v4: 4.3.3 URLs for Related Entities with Referential Constraints](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_URLsforRelatedEntitieswithReferentia) your syntax is compliant as long as `Porducts` is a collection type.

> Include the relevant `$metadata` for the resources in question in the future to resolve this level of ambiguity.

If your second form of URL worked, then it usually indicates that the multiplicity of the `Products` navigation property is singular, making it no longer a collection and therefore you cannot filter by the *key*. In this case, as above you could use the `$filter` query option, but then you might as well have queried the `Categories` controller directly.

---

Even if the syntax is compliant and the resource navigation to `Products` *IS* a collection, in many implementations this type of specificity in navigation is NOT supported. Maybe because it is unnecessary but probably because it is a grey area in terms of intent so it is hard for code frameworks to enforce routing conventions or rules in this area by default.

For instance, should this query be evaluated by the `Customers` controller, but return a collection of `Category` resource, or should this be evaluated by the `Products` controller to return a collection of `Category` resource? Wouldn't it be easier to design the underlying controllers if the `Category` controller was the one to return and query the `Category` resources, rather than potentially adding this same support to all of the `Customer`,`Product` and `Category` controllers?

Given that the *unique key* of `10` has been provided for the expected `Product` resource to return, the `Customer` *key* of `1` is irrelevant.

If you wanted to deliberately return a `Product` resource with a *key* of `10`, but *only if* it belongs to a `Customer` with a *key* of `1` then you could also specify that query in the following forms:

```
~/MyService/Products(10)/Categories?$filter=Product/CustomerFK eq 1
~/MyService/Products(10)/Categories?$filter=Product/Customer/PK eq 1
```

or you can query the Category controller directly:

```
~/MyService/Categories?$filter=Products/any(p:p/Customer/PK eq 1 and p/Category/PK eq 10)
```

Whilst service authors can choose to support multi level navigation as the specification suggests and OP has attempted, it is not always offered *out of the box* and as such we tend to forget to implement it at all. Its not always hard to do, often we just need to implement some simple routes, but due to the variability of the interpretation and implementation, I personally only ever support navigating 1 level deep but do not allow *key* selector at the child level.

If the service you are querying does not support it, then simply target the `Category` resources directly through the `Cateogry` or indirectly through the `Product` controller with an appropriate filter.